# Woocommerce Terms and conditions link - checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I would like to add Terms and conditions link to my woocommerce checkout page.

I have set: WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advanced -> Page settings -> Terms

I have set: Appearance -> Customize -> WooCommerce -> Checkout

I am using Flatsome theme. I've tried to disable every plugin that affect checkout but still, nothing.

It still showing plain text "I accept Terms and Conditions".

I tried "live preview" on another template but the same effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WordPress admin dashboard and then go to Pages > **Add new.**

Add Your Title as Terms and Condition
Add content
Review the content and save it or you can publish it if everything okay.

Now you need to set your Terms and condition page in WooCommerce. Go to **Appearance** > **Customize**

From the customize page dashboard select **WooCommerce** > **Checkout**

From checkout click on the terms and condition tab. A drop-down menu will appear and you can see your created **terms and condition** page there. Select the page and save the settings.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://niamrox.com/how-to-add-terms-and-conditions-to-the-checkout-page-on-woocommerce/) for better understanding